# Django - Get I/O error on changing object attribute

Tags: python, django, model, io, save

In my `views.py` file, I am trying to add 1 to a BigIntegerField named `visited_counter`.

views.py :

```
def view_page(request,id_page):

   page = get_object_or_404(Page,title=id_page)
   page.visited_counter= page.visited_counter +1
   page.save()

   return render(request,'app/page.html',locals())
```

models.py :

```
class Page(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   visited_counter= models.BigIntegerField()
   landscape= models.BooleanField()
   thumbnail = models.ImageField(storage=OverwriteStorage(),upload_to=thumbnail_path)
   backgroundpicture =models.ImageField(storage=OverwriteStorage(),upload_to=background_path)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

       if self.backgroundpicture.width >= self.backgroundpicture.height:
           self.landscape=True

       else:
           self.landscape=False

       if self.backgroundpicture:
           from PIL import Image
           import glob, os
           from cStringIO import StringIO
           from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

           image = Image.open(self.backgroundpicture)   ####LINE ERROR####

           try:
               # thumbnail
               THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (160, 160)  # dimensions

               # Convert to RGB if necessary
               if image.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'): image = image.convert('RGB')

               # create a thumbnail + use antialiasing for a smoother thumbnail
               image.thumbnail(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)

               # fetch image into memory
               temp_handle = StringIO()
               image.save(temp_handle, 'JPEG')
               temp_handle.seek(0)

               # save it
               file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(self.backgroundpicture.name.rpartition('/')[-1])
               suf = SimpleUploadedFile(file_name + file_ext, temp_handle.read(), content_type='JPEG')

               self.thumbnail.save(file_name + '.jpg', suf, save=False)
           except ImportError:
               pass
       super(Page, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I create a 'Page object', I have no problem.... The save function is doing her job very well, but when I want to access to the object via the `view_page` function. I get a `I/O operation on closed file` error on that line: `image = Image.open(self.backgroundpicture)`.

I didn't find any other Q/A related to this case, so I am stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to add an if condition in your save method and check if it is necessary to read the whole code in the save function.

For this you add a function named, `has_changed`

```
def has_changed(instance, field, manager='objects'):
    """Returns true if a field has changed in a model

    May be used in a model.save() method.

    """
    if not instance.pk:
        return True
    manager = getattr(instance.__class__, manager)
    old = getattr(manager.get(pk=instance.pk), field)
    return not getattr(instance, field) == old
```

And you use it in the model definition like this:

```
if has_changed(self, 'backgroundpicture'):

       if self.backgroundpicture.width >= self.backgroundpicture.height:
           self.landscape=True
...
```